# Add a Delete Button to my Gallery script

Tags: php

I've made an image gallery to work with my instant image capture program I've made. I've got all the images from the directory to display correctly but I want to add a delete button which can delete the images. Here's my code so far (minus the HTML).

```
<?php

$ip = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
$folderName = md5($ip);
$dir = ''.$folderName.'';
$file_display = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif');

if (file_exists($dir) == false) {
    echo "<b>Your Folder</b> ( $dir ) <b>cannot be found. Please contact the site     developer.</b><br>";
} else {
    $dir_contents = scandir($dir);

    foreach ($dir_contents as $file) {
        $file_type = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file)));

        if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' && in_array($file_type, $file_display)     == true) {
            echo '<div style="margin-bottom:15px;"><img src="', $dir, '/',     $file, '" alt="', $file, '" /><br /><a class="button">Delete</a></div><br />';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

How would I got about making the link with the class "button" able to delete the image which is displayed? I'm not very experienced with PHP so a good explanation would be of great help and appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to have the delete button/link bind to some sort of identifier for the image such as an ID or file name. When the delete button/link is clicked the identifier is carried across to the delete script which which "unlink" the image file assuming it's on the same server and you have access/permissions for it.

Here are some resources for you.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

If you do not know where to go from here i suggest looking up POST/GET and also look into security methods for deleting files proprly.

Good Luck.